# SignalR: connect to one hub from javascript, not to all of them

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

The following connects the js client to all the existent hubs:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).done(function () {});
```

Is there some way to connect to some particular hub instead?

If not, what is the point of "OnConnected()" and "OnDisconnected()" being in EVERY hub? if all of them are going to be called anyway.

I'm asking this because there is a particular html (something like a news feed) in which I want to handle notifications from one hub (when news are posted, this view should handle and show them appearing). I'm going to use groups but seems more natural to separate this in hubs.

Answer (score 2):

You only subscribe to hubs that you have client side events associated with.  So lets say you had two hubs:

1. **hubA**
2. **hubB**

In your client if you have:

```
var hubA = $.connection.hubA;

hubA.client.foo = function() {};

$.connection.hub.start();
```

You will only be subscribed to events on hubA (not hubB).

Comment: But both OnConnected (hubA's OnConnected and hubB's OnConnected) will be called. So you are in fact connected to both hubs.

Comment: @sports Hubs share a single connection but you don't receive messages if you aren't subscribed

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use or not use the connection events in any hubs you create. You certainly can separate your code into logical sections using hubs, no harm in that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var connection = $.hubConnection(server);
var someHub= connection.createHubProxy("someHub");
connection.start({transport: 'longPolling'}).done(function () {})
```